# AWS Gem Build Error when deploying Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nokogiri, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to switch to AWS and Elastic Beanstalk. I was able to get a successful sample instance of AWS going. I am trying to deploy my Rails application and got this error:

```
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.6.6.2), and Bundler cannot
  continue.
  Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.6.2'` succeeds before bundling. (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I tried adding:

```
commands:
  build_nokigiri:
    command: bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
```

to the config.yml in .elasticbeanstalk, but that didn't seem to change the error output.

I don't experience a problem on my local server, so my hunch is that I need to do some extra setup on the cloud server. I'm wondering if my approach is right, or what I am missing.

Comment: try to uninstall nokogiri and then install it

Comment: can you explain why this would change the behavior i see on the server? the Gemfile.lock that gets uploaded would essentially be the same.

Comment: Obviously you will have to again push your code to git by uninstalling nokog iri and reinstalling it .And then push your code to git and then push your code to server

Comment: I uninstalled nokogiri, ran bundle install, experienced the same error on the local side that I saw on aws. After I ran the above command(bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries) and then bundle install, things worked again. So I am confident that I just need to figure out how to run this command correctly on the server end